# Is there a way to make this more efficient (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab

I've figured out a method that works for my purposes, however I would like to make the solution generalizable to more numbers of trials without having to hard-code a new if-statement for every increase in trials.  Right now trials=4 and if I wanted to make trials=5 I would need to write a new if-statement.

```
if new_A == 1:trials;
   outer_matrices{:,1} = A;
end
if new_A == trials+1:trials*2;
   outer_matrices{:,2} = A;
end
if new_A == (trials*2)+1:trials*3;
   outer_matrices{:,3} = A;
end
if new_A == (trials*3)+1:trials*4;
   outer_matrices{:,4} = A;
end
```

You see the pattern (with trials=5 I would need to multiply by 4 and 5 respectively and then change to outer_matrices{:,5})

I'm sure there's a fairly simple solution/structure that I'm just not thinking of.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just checked and Schorsch's does work as new_A is referring to a number x in x:x+trials.  Thank you all a ton for helping out!

Comment: turned my comment into an answer, if you want to accept one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (no loops or conditionals approach) -

```
N = 5;%%// Number of cases
ind = find(all(bsxfun(@eq,reshape(1:trials*N,trials,[]),new_A'),1))
outer_matrices{:,ind} = A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it `new_A` is a vector with `trials` number of elements. As `(trials*n)+1:trials*(n+1)` is a vector of the form `[trials*n+1, trials*n+2, ... ]` you can do:

```
if ~mod(new_A(1)-1,trials) && all(diff(new_A) == 1)
   outerMatrices{(trials+new_A(1)-1)/trials} = A;
end
```

What it does is:

`~mod(new_A(1)-1,trials)` uses the [modulus](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) operation, to check if the first element in `new_A` is divisible by trials. If it is, the `mod` will return `0`. The `~` in front of `mod` means "not", thus if `mod` returns zero, this will evaluate to "~0 == 1".

`all(diff(new_A)==1)` checks if all the elements in `new_A` is a exactly one element apart.

Answer (score 0):

A basic `for`-loop approach to mirror the code in the question would be:

```
N=5;
for ii=1:N
    if new_A == trials*(ii-1)+1:trials*ii
        outer_matrices{:,ii} = A;
    end
end
```